# Симметрическая разность множеств

Tags: python, python-3.x

Симметрическая разность множеств
Реализуйте бинарную операцию над множествами — симметрическую разность. Её результатом являются те элементы двух множеств, которые принадлежат ровно одному из множеств (но не принадлежат их пересечению).

Входные данные
В первой строке записано натуральное число — количество элементов первого множества. Во второй строке через пробел перечислены эти элементы (натуральные числа). В третьей строке указано количество элементов второго множества (натуральное). В четвертой строке перечислены через пробел элементы второго множества (натуральные числа). Множества во входных данных могут быть неупорядочены и содержать равные элементы.

Выходные данные
Результат требуется вывести в том же формате: сначала количество элементов, полученных в результате операции, затем (если получено ненулевое количество элементов) вывести сами элементы в порядке возрастания. Множество в выводе должно быть упорядочено, и все элементы его должны быть различными.
Пример
Ввод
3
1 2 3
2
3 4
Вывод
3
1 2 4
Мой код:

```
a=int(input())
A=set(input())
b=int(input())
B=set(input())
C = A.symmetric_difference(B)
print(len(C))
C=sorted(C)
for n in C:
    print(n, end = ' ')
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку. В проверке пишет ошибку. Вроде пример выполняет, а проверку не проходит. Правда, я не задействую переменные а и b.

Comment: Может, дело в формате вывода? Попробуйте заменить последний цикл на `print(*C, sep=' ')`.

Comment: Не сработало. Пишет, что программа выдает неверный ответ. Может ли это быть из-за того, что я как-то не так считаю? Хотя A.symmetric_difference(B) как раз и считает симметрическую разность, а дальше я лишь сортирую по величине.

Comment: В логике программы нет проблем. Так что проблема либо во вводе значений, либо в выводе.

Comment: Проблема в отрицательных числах

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в отрицательных числах: `print(set('-1 0 1')) == {' ', '-', '1', '0'}`.

Попробуйте так:

```py
n_1 = input()
A = set(map(int, input().split()))

n_2 = input()
B = set(map(int, input().split()))

C = A.symmetric_difference(B)
C = sorted(C)

print(len(C))
print(*C, sep=' ')
```

Comment: Да! Спасибо вам огромное! Теперь вижу, как и где я напортачила.